How to update weights of a generator
I would like to update the weights of a stylegan generator. I have the weights delta. Is this the correct approach:
def add_weights_delta(generator, weights_delta):
    with torch.no_grad():
        for name, parameter in generator.named_parameters():
            if name in weights_delta:
                parameter.data += weights_delta[name]

I tried this and did not get any errors. It seems correct, but just wanted to confirm. e
def add_weights_delta(generator, weights_delta):
    with torch.no_grad():
        for name, parameter in generator.named_parameters():
            if name in weights_delta:
                parameter.data += weights_delta[name]

